# Looking for the name of a voting process by public token

Tags: voting, direct-democracy, electronic-voting

I though about doing a publicly verifiable voting system, here is the idea:

- You give each voter a random random corresponding to his vote
- You make every vote public as a list of (voting number, vote)

So every vote is anonymous and you don't have to trust the voting system, you can easily see that that your vote is correctly taken into account. (In the case of an US election for example).

I think it already exists and I'm looking for papers/articles on the subject. So, what's the name of a similar system ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to implement an electronic voting system which is as secure as pen-and-paper voting?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24/is-it-possible-to-implement-an-electronic-voting-system-which-is-as-secure-as-pe)

Comment: I disagree, I was looking for the *name* of this kind of process

Comment: Generally [Guessing Game Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) do not work well on SE.

Comment: You are right, I agree that based on this this can be considerate as a duplicate (especially since the duplicate contains the answer to my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this talk about the exact same idea: http://www.ted.com/talks/david_bismark_e_voting_without_fraud

Via this answer:
https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/46/2906

An implementation: https://vote.heliosvoting.org/